Taking looped inputs and outputs
Think of me trying to make a program that goes on to calculate Fibonacci numbers in a sequential order forever. I want to make the command produce output and treat the output as an input by performing some operation on it. How would I write such a program in python and how would I get it to stop if it's not going to automatically stop after a certain point?
So I have tried manually inputting values but don't know how to do it automatically as I am a newbie.

Hi! You might be interested in generators. Write your Fibonacci function using the yield keyword instead of return, as an infinite loop that yields fib0 then yields fib1 then yields fib2 etc.


to calculate Fibonacci numbers in a sequential order...

So you'd have a function for that calculation. A generator could be a choice:
def gen_fib():
    a, b = 0, 1  # Let's start the sequence with 1 (not 0)
    while True:
        yield b
        a, b = b, a+b


...forever.

That suggests you would just keep iterating over the iterator with a for loop:
for a in gen_fib():
    # ...


I want to make the command produce output...

for a in gen_fib():
    print(a)  # output


...and treat the output as an input by performing some operation on it.

prev = 2
for a in gen_fib():
    print(a)  # output
    ratio = a / prev  # calculation
    prev = a


how would I get it to stop if it's not going to automatically stop after a certain point?

It is up to you to define the condition for when the program should stop. This could be the user just killing the program (then there is nothing to do), or some satisfactory state that is reached. For instance, maybe you want to print the ratio of two consecutive Fibonacci numbers, which is known to converge, and exit when that calculated ratio isn't changing by much anymore:
def gen_fib():
    a, b = 0, 1  # Let's start the sequence with 1 (not 0)
    while True:
        yield b
        a, b = b, a+b


prev, prev_ratio = 2, 2
for a in gen_fib():
    ratio = a / prev   # calculation
    print(a, ratio)  # output
    if abs(ratio - prev_ratio) < 1e-16:
        break  # That ratio is good enough!
    prev, prev_ratio = a, ratio


I suggest taking a look at generator functions.
As an example, here is a generator function that goes on to yield even numbers forever:
def gen_even():
    k = 0
    while True:
        yield k
        k += 2

Then you can use this function to get a few even numbers and perform operations on them:
for i, even_number in zip(range(10), gen_even()):
    square = even_number**2
    print(f'The {i}th even number is {even_number} and its square is {square}.')

Output:
The 0th even number is 0 and its square is 0.
The 1th even number is 2 and its square is 4.
The 2th even number is 4 and its square is 16.
The 3th even number is 6 and its square is 36.
The 4th even number is 8 and its square is 64.
The 5th even number is 10 and its square is 100.
The 6th even number is 12 and its square is 144.
The 7th even number is 14 and its square is 196.
The 8th even number is 16 and its square is 256.
The 9th even number is 18 and its square is 324.

Alternatively you can assign the generator to a variable and pull the next numbers from it using next:
g = gen_even()
for i in range(5):
    even_number = next(g)
    # some operations...


with recursion
You used the recursion tag, so I'll offer a solution that approaches the problem recursively -
const fib =
  stream(0, () =>
    stream(1, () =>
      streamAdd(fib, fib.next)))

Intuitively stream takes a value and a thunk, () => ... which evaluates to the next stream -
const stream = (value, next) => ({
  value,
  get next() {
    delete this.next
    return this.next = next() // evaluates at most once
  }
})

The stream function creates ordinary objects, allowing us to write streamAdd which simply adds two streams together. We use emptyStream to terminate finite streams -
const emptyStream =
  Symbol('emptyStream')

const streamAdd = (s1, s2) => {
  if (s1 == emptyStream) return emptyStream
  if (s2 == emptyStream) return emptyStream
  return stream(
    s1.value + s2.value,
    () => streamAdd(s1.next, s2.next),
  )
}

We can visualize the infinite fib stream, where ... is equal to the result of streamAdd(fib, fib.next) -
       fib  0 -> 1 -> ...
            +
  fib.next  1 -> ...
            =

streamAdd(
  fib,
  fib.next
)           1

       fib  0 -> 1 -> 1 -> ...
            +    +
  fib.next  1 -> 1 -> ...
            =    =

streamAdd(
  fib,
  fib.next
)           1 -> 2

       fib  0 -> 1 -> 1 -> 2 -> ...
            +    +    +
  fib.next  1 -> 1 -> 2 -> ...
            =    =    =

streamAdd(
  fib,
  fib.next
)           1 -> 2 -> 3

       fib  0 -> 1 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> ...
            +    +    +    +
  fib.next  1 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> ...
            =    =    =    =

streamAdd(
  fib,
  fib.next
)           1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 5

       fib  0 -> 1 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 5 -> ...
            +    +    +    +    +
  fib.next  1 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 5 -> ...
            =    =    =    =    =

streamAdd(
  fib,
  fib.next
)           1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 5 -> 8

       fib  0 -> 1 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 5 -> 8 -> ...
            +    +    +    +    +    +
  fib.next  1 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 5 -> 8 -> ...
            =    =    =    =    =    =

streamAdd(
  fib,
  fib.next
)           1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 5 -> 8 -> 13

Run the program below to see the first 10 fibonacci numbers -


const emptyStream =
  Symbol('emptyStream')

const stream = (value, next) => ({
  value,
  get next() {
    delete this.next
    return this.next = next()
  },
})

const streamAdd = (s1, s2) => {
  if (s1 == emptyStream) return emptyStream
  if (s2 == emptyStream) return emptyStream
  return stream(
    s1.value + s2.value,
    () => streamAdd(s1.next, s2.next),
  )
}

const fib =
  stream(0, () =>
    stream(1, () =>
      streamAdd(fib, fib.next)))

for (let s = fib, i = 0; i < 10; s = s.next, i = i + 1)
  console.log(s.value)
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }



with more recursion
It probably feels unnatural to handle the stream using a for loop. stream is originally introduced in this Q&A, where we will see other stream functions. Observe the correlation between recursive data structure and recursive procedure. These two in particular are useful for converting an infinite stream into a finite array -
const take = (s = emptyStream, n = 0) =>
  s === emptyStream || n <= 0
    ? emptyStream
    : stream(s.value, _ => take(s.next, n - 1))
    
const toArray = (s = emptyStream) =>
  s === emptyStream
    ? []
    : [ s.value, ...toArray(s.next) ]

Here's the first 10 elements of the fib stream converted to an array -
toArray(take(fib, 10))

[ 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34 ]

Run the program again to convert the stream to an array -


const emptyStream =
  Symbol('emptyStream')

const stream = (value, next) => ({
  value,
  get next() {
    delete this.next
    return this.next = next()
  },
})

const streamAdd = (s1, s2) => {
  if (s1 == emptyStream) return emptyStream
  if (s2 == emptyStream) return emptyStream
  return stream(
    s1.value + s2.value,
    () => streamAdd(s1.next, s2.next),
  )
}

const take = (s = emptyStream, n = 0) =>
  s === emptyStream || n <= 0
    ? emptyStream
    : stream(s.value, _ => take(s.next, n - 1))
    
const toArray = (s = emptyStream) =>
  s === emptyStream
    ? []
    : [ s.value, ...toArray(s.next) ]

const fib =
  stream(0, () =>
    stream(1, () =>
      streamAdd(fib, fib.next)))

console.log(toArray(take(fib, 10)))
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }



The original post contains a version of toArray that I would not write today. It uses recursion and demonstrates the best ergonomics, so I chose to include it, however it is an extremely inefficient function. A lesson here is that by creating abstractions like stream we gain tuning points to optimize parts of our program without having to rewrite the others -
const toArray = (s = emptyStream) => {
  const arr = []
  for (let m = s; m !== emptyStream; m = m.next)
    arr.push(m.value)
  return arr
}

